# How to mock ftp server for unit testing in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, ftp, mocha.js, sinon, chai

Could anybody tell me how to mock the FTP connection and downloading the file from FTP client for unit testing in nodeJS?

I'm using FTP node module for connecting to FTP/SFTP client
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp)

Comment: This depends on how you use the module. I guess you just need to mock all its methods.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found a way to mock the FTP client...
we need to stub on the main class like this.

To Triger Ready:
sinon.stub(Client.prototype, 'connect').withArgs(connect).callsFake(function (options) {
  this.emit('ready'); 
});

To Trigger Error:
sinon.stub(Client.prototype, 'connect').withArgs(connect).callsFake(function (options) {
  this.emit('error'); 
});

let connect ={
     host:hostname,
     port:port,
     user:user,
     password:password
}

Comment: hello! I'm doing this, but the event doesn't start... Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) to mock the `ftp` module.